# my macbook doesn't detect the battery ubuntu 20

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel, battery, detect

Hi sorry for bad english, is not my natural language. I do stared to have problems with my battery went my laptop doesn't detect the battery so I change macSierraOS to Ubuntu to see if it fixes, but it doesn't. I think could it be something with the kernel but I don know to much of these areas, so if you can help me it woulb be great.

Is importan to mention that in some moment the icon of the battery appears for two or more hours, then it just desapears.

procesor: Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P7550 @ 2.26GHz × 2
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS  64 bits
Thanks.

Comment: If you had the same problem om MacOS, then this is a hardware problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for your opinion. The think is that I went to some tecniques and they say that it isn't a hardware problem, but coult it be. But I still think is wierd that the laptop recognize de battery in one oportunity like a week or two ago and I had this problemt since two or three month ago.

Comment: Usually it has nothing to do with the Kernel when a battery is having issues.  It probably is hardware since you have tried in the Mac OS as well.  But, it could also be the PRAM needing to be reset, etc.  https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063  also see https://www.macworld.com/article/2881177/how-to-reset-a-macs-nvram-pram-and-smc.html

Comment: Thanks. sorry that I retard my answer but I dont't have internet all the time. I will prove to reset the pram. In act I do it in the first instand but it bring me some problems with de sistem MacSierra so I decide to change to linux.

Comment: I think it can be solved cause how I tell you, it just work for some minutes until I shutdown the sistem, but I never make any change before, than can justify this beheavor. So it could be somethng with the intangible part of the sistem, and as ypu say could be the pram. I supose that the action to try is the same with the old sistem. I will read the information that you subgest in the link below. Thanks a lot.